# Rashi with sources in context

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, rashi, pentateuch-chumash

Is there a sefer chumash with Rashi's commentary which brings Rashi's sources in context?

For example, if Rashi were to quote a gemara, this sefer would print the relevant text of the gemara in the sefer.

Comment: Rashi Elucidated by Artscroll, I saw a sample recently, didn't really go throught it ,but would assume "Elucidated " would maybe give more context ...

Comment: I don't think so. Most just reference Rashi's source for you to look up on your own.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's Chumash Rashi Ha'Shalem by Mosdot Ariel ([link](https://mosdot-ariel.co.il/product/%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9-%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9D/)). Also available on Otzar Hachochmah. Here's an example of one page:

[image: 1st page of Chumash Rashi Ha'Shalem]

Comment: do you know if they completed the series?

Comment: According to their website they recently finished Vayikra.

Comment: @Shababnik The next best thing I can recommend is the series מקורות רש"י by חיים זהרי which brings Rashi's sources on the entire Tanach, but not in chumash format. A few of the books are available on Otzar Hachochmah but not the entire series.

Comment: Much obliged for your suggestions!